# Consuming a Razor Class Library with Partial Views in .Net Framework Project

Tags: c#, vb.net, asp.net-core, razor, razor-class-library

I have recently come across Razor Class Libraries and am not 100% sure of what can / can't be achieved with them, but am very much liking the concept of being able to create views (and partial views) which can be shared within multiple web projects.

However, whilst I know a bit of C# and am quite familiar with the conversion tools, I am 1000 times more proficient with VB.Net and consequently most of my work is coded that way. .NET Core, as far as I can deduce does not support VB.NET.

I followed the tutorial and downloaded the sample code from here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/ui-class?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

With this I was able to build a solution containing a RCL and a .NetCore website which uses views and partial views from the RCL.

I was able to build multiple .NETCore Websites and all I had to do was to add a reference to the RCL Project and they would all use the shared partial views in the RCL... everything worked well.

EXCEPT, I don't want a .NETCore website project because I want to stick with VB.NET, so I read up and am told that the RCL I have created using .netstandard2.0 should be compatible with the .Net Framework.

**Note; Essentially, for the immediate requirements, I intend to use an RCL predominently for creating partial views to be shared across multiple projects. I am happy to create them using C# for the project logic, and a lot of my code logic already exists in VB class libraries which I can import, but don't want to have to rewrite or relearn everything I have already done in the main bulk of my projects.**

Upgrading all my work to .NetCore would be a nightmare in one go anyway...

So....

- I created a VB Web Application targeting .Net Framework 4.7.2.
- I add a reference to my RCL
- I ran a Build to check there were no version conflicts or reference incompatibilities
- I ran the website to check no build errors that weren't caught by Visual Studio

All the above worked fine, the reference added OK, no problems at all.

BUT... I cannot work out how to get the partial views in the RCL to be accessible to the website.

I am constantly getting the error

```
The partial view '****' was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations.
```

Can anyone tell me

- How to hook up a Razor Class Library in order for Partial Views to be consumed in a .Net Framework Project?
- Am I (quite likely knowing me) trying to do something that is simply not meant to work like that?!

**EDIT...**

Quite reasonably asked by Ben in the comments below, to clarify exactly what I'm doing

Firstly. I am literally just experimenting with a new Solution, so each time I am adding Projects I am literally just going to "Add New project  > *select*". I am not editing the projects beyond the templates created by Visual Studio (2019 Community Edition if it makes any difference) except to add the reference to my RCl.

The RCL has a single partial view which I am trying to display, it's contents are:

```
@using RazorUIClassLib
<h1>This is nothing but a test</h1>
```

Where obviously `RazorUIClassLib` is the name of the RCL... there is nothing else in it at all at this stage.

File structure is

```
> Pages > Shared > Test.cshtml
```

I have a C# .NETCore Project called `WebApp1` which is the exact Project from the example downloaded from the link above has a relevant file structure

```
> Pages > Index.cshtml
```

In Index.cshtml I have added this line:

```
<partial name="Test"/>
```

(Note; Visual Studio seems a little iffy about finding the Test file as intellisense (ReSharper) is saying `cannot resolve partial view'Test'`, but it runs fine)

I have a second C# .netcore project which I added to make sure there wasn't something "special" about the one I downloaded from the example code, that is structured exactly as the Visual Studio Template, and has a slightly different file structure:

> Views > Home > Index.cshtml

The same single line of code is added to this file as above and works just the same (all I did after adding this brand new project was to add this line and the reference to my RCL Project)

The **problem** Project is a VB Project, which obviously is targeting .Net Framework NOT CORE. It is literally just the default file structure created by Visual Studio when adding a new MVC Project to the Solution, so we have

> Views > Home > Index.vbhtml

Again, I have done nothing to it except to add the reference to my RCL Project and this line:

```
@Html.Partial("Test")
```

I have also tried

```
@Html.Partial("/Pages/Shared/Test")
@Html.Partial("~/Pages/Shared/Test")
@Html.Partial("/RazorUIClassLib/Pages/Shared/Test")
@Html.Partial("~/RazorUIClassLib/Pages/Shared/Test")
```

And also all the above with the .cshtml file extension.

In all cases I get varying forms of this error:

```
The partial view 'Test' was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/Home/Test.aspx
~/Views/Home/Test.ascx
~/Views/Shared/Test.aspx
~/Views/Shared/Test.ascx
~/Views/Home/Test.cshtml
~/Views/Home/Test.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/Test.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/Test.vbhtml
```

Clearly from the error it is expecting to find the Partial in the `Views` Directory, but as I mention, if I add the full path I still get the same error but with different "I tried looking here" type notes.

I keep saying that I haven't changed anything to clarify that I have not made any routing alterations... am wondering if I should, but if so, not sure what!

Comment: Can you post what your page that is consuming the partial view looks like? All your other assumptions are correct - the error message you've posted makes it seem like a pretty easy fix (fingers crossed).

Comment: @BenSampica thank you, I have added some more information.

Comment: Oh -  to add to the list of things I have tried, I have also tried changing the directory in the RCL to `>  Views > Shared > Test.cshtml` following the implication from the errors that the project is expecting a file structure like that, rather than `> Pages > Shared > Test.cshtml`

Answer (score 1):

So it looks like *my* assumptions were wrong. Even though they can target .NET Standard, RCL's are an ASP.NET Core feature **only**. You can see on their [documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/ui-class?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) that the only versions supported are ASP.NET Core products. However you would be able to share view models and business logic in the RCL but that's the extent of it.

Comment: Ugh.  What’s the point of it being able to target .net standard then if in that instance it essentially amounts to nothing but a standard class library.  I find the documentation on all this stuff pretty vague to be honest. It’s like they’re not even trying anymore!

Comment: I suppose to make this work, I could feasibly take all my actual code in my projects out and make separate class libraries which contain all that in VB and simply build a new UI around .NetCore, introducing small RCL projects as I go.

Comment: Yeah that would be the way to do it! Good luck - sorry it didn't work out quite as you expected.